# How to find from JPA repository by any fields?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

There is JPA entity User, this is just example:

```
@Entity
User{
 @Id
 String name;
 @Id
 String surname;
 @Id 
 String age;
}
```

It works and successfully saves.

I use repository and for get by name, I create method like this

```
findUserByName(String name)
```

But how to find entities using repository by any fields, f.e. by name and by surname together?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Do you really have `@Id` on every field? Looks weird.

Comment: You should also specify: Do you want to know how to *combine* specific fields, so generate a method `findUserByNameAndSurname` (what would be the solution, by the way), or do you want to know how to get a "generic" method which accepts some kind of "filter" syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of options here. You can use similar way

```
findUserByNameAndAge(String name, String age)
```

or use `@Query` annotation

or `Specification` interface

Comment: `Specification` interface looks really nice, didn't know about that!